# How to get vue-router in index.html?

Tags: vuejs2

In **index.html** :

```
<script>
function demoFunction(name) {
    this.$router.push({name: 'Succ'})
}
```

Why `this.$router` is `undefined`? How can I get `vue-router`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like You defined the function in the global scope, so `this` inside your function will point to the global object which is `window` in the browser. `window` does not have the property `$router` , that's the reason you get undefined.

You can use `this.$router` inside your vue options only and that too :

- if you created a new router instance like this

  ```
  var router = new VueRouter({
      routes:[
          //your route objects
      ]
  });
  ```
- and then passed this router instance as a property to the root vue instance

  ```
  new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router: router
  });
  ```